# how to delete particular row by id from database on corresponding button click using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table

i want to delete a row of a Html table from database respective with their id by using angularJS and i'm new in angularJS so is there any way to achive this? Thanks in Advance

i have used table like this

```
<table class="table details">
<thead> 
<tr>
<th sort-by="firstName">Title Initial_Phase</th>
<th sort-by="lastName">Travel From</th>
<th sort-by="created_at">Travel To</th>
<th sort-by="birthDate" sort-init="desc">From-To Date</th>
<th sort-by="birthDate" sort-init="desc">Budget</th>
<th sort-by="birthDate" sort-init="desc">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="issue in issues | filter:filter">
<td><strong><a href="/ViewBid/Index?{{ issue.ID }}" />{{ issue.Title }}             </strong></td>

<td><a href="/ViewBid/Index?{{ issue.ID }}" />{{ issue.Travel_From }}</td>
<td><a href="/ViewBid/Index?{{ issue.ID }}" />{{ issue.Travel_To }}</td>
<td><a href="/ViewBid/Index?{{ issue.ID }}" />{{ issue.From_Date | date }} -        {{ issue.To_Date | date }}</td>

<td><a href="/ViewBid/Index?{{ issue.ID }}" />{{ issue.Budget_Max }}</td>
<td><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Need more details. Do you have api url's? any html page markup?

Comment: @YatinGera thank you for replying

Comment: @YatinGera even i get that how to get id of particular row then it will be easy to do further coding

Comment: when you get the list of rows from the server, get the id's aswell. Use ng-repeat to bind the items to you html. This way each row will have a property on its scope called id as ng-repeat creates new scope for each item. On the delete button, just pass that id to your controller that can make an http delete request to server to delete the item. Hope it helps

Comment: So what exactly are you saying? That you're too lazy to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're asking about?! Yes you are lazy - All your other questions are like that

Comment: @alton Eitan Now i Provide minimal of my exapmle

Comment: @YatinGera Thank you i'm trying to work on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example:

```
<table class="table table-bordered"
    <thead><th>Name </th>
            <th>Delete</th>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="data in List">
            <td>{{data.Name }}</td>
            <td> <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
     ng-bootbox-confirm='R U Sure to Delete' ng-bootbox-confirm-action="delete(data)" ng-bootbox-confirm-action-cancel="confirmCallbackCancel   

(attr1, attr2)" /></td>
    </tr>
```

`

Here is the angular Controller:

```
`$scope.delete = function (data) {
        AngularService.delete(data)
        .success(function (data) {
            alert("Data Delete");
        })
        .error(function () {
            $ngBootbox.alert('@Resources.ResourceCommon.MsgNot_deleted');
        });
    }`
```

And in Angular Factory

```
 delete: function (data) {
            return $http({
                url: 'url path',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data
            })
        }
```